# Process and Thread in Rest API

Tags: java

Can some one help to understand,  my doubt i have regarding Process and Thread in Rest api

1. Say i have created a rest api serverName/employees to get all employees and deployed in Tomcat server .Just assume it is  receiving 1000 calls same time. How rest API handle 1000 calls? Will it process request in sequential order? Or it that something related to connection pool on server (is there any default connection pool for tomcat)?
2. If this is handled asys then it will be consider as a separate process?
3. If we are using threading then it will only withing single process i.e each process use their own threads without interacting with other process?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How Tomcat handles multiple requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14567153/how-tomcat-handles-multiple-requests)

Comment: Don't think so its a duplicate